# how to make layout responsive with bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I'm needing help with situation.. I don't know very things about "front-end" and I need to create a layout responsive..

I have this website:

http://fotosfrontend2018.azurewebsites.net/

when I run it on PC it's work, but when I run in my cell phone, the images they are messy..

How could I resolve this?

tks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please **[read how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and 
[what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
It's expected that *you* **make an effort to solve the problem *before* asking**. Remember that questions should be helpful to future readers. Please post the relevant code in the question instead of linking to external sites that may change over time.

Comment: See http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options